# Sequelize: How associate two fields from a table another table

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following table settings from my sequelize.

```
const Accounts = sequelize.define('Accounts', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
});

const Transfers = sequelize.define('Transfers', {
  value: {
    type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 2),
    defaultValue: 0,
  },
  accountIdFrom: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  accountIdTo: DataTypes.INTEGER,
});

Transfers.belongsTo(Accounts, { foreignKey: 'accountIdFrom' });
Transfers.belongsTo(Accounts, { foreignKey: 'accountIdTo' });

const data = await Transfers.findAll({
  include: [{ model: Accounts }]
});
```

Return:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "value": "10.00",
  "accountIdFrom": 1,
  "accountIdTo": 2,
  "Account": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Banco Neon",
  }
}
```

I tried to use the association setting this way, but the sequelize always associates with just one field, and I want it to either show for both fields. `accountIdFrom` and`acountIdTo`.

The expected return should be something like this, but, it is not working:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "value": "10.00",
  "accountIdFrom": 2,
  "accountIdTo": 1,
  "AccountFrom": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bank Two",
  },
  "AccountTo": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bank One",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `as:` instead of `foreignKey:`

```
Transfers.belongsTo(Accounts, { as: 'accountFrom', onDelete: 'cascade', onUpdate: 'no action' });
Transfers.belongsTo(Accounts, { as: 'accountTo', onDelete: 'cascade', onUpdate: 'no action' });
```

This will give you on your `Accounts` model the columns `accountFromId` and `accountToId`. So when you need to include the models you're going to do it like this:

```
Transfers.find( {
  where: {},
  include: [{
    model: db.Accounts,
    as: 'accountFrom'
  },{
    model: db.Accounts,
    as: 'accountTo'
  }]
})
```

Comment: @DavidCosta how did it go?

Comment: Ei, @Ellebkey, i test, but did not work. https://github.com/davidcostadev/mymoney/pull/11/files, and i get this error: 
`Error: Naming collision between attribute 'accountFrom' and association 'accountFrom' on model Transfers. To remedy this, change either foreignKey or as in your association definition`

Comment: I see your code, you dont have to define the colums on the model, either the foreignkey, with the `belongsTo` sequelize create the association by itself. On your `create-transfer.js` remove the lines from 14 to 19, and 32 to 56. I also updated my answer.

Comment: I do what you said, and get a error: 
`Error: Naming collision between attribute 'accountFrom' and association 'accountFrom' on model Transfers. To remedy this, change either foreignKey or as in your association definition`

Comment: I find the error, i was define on account model the wrong field foreign key on transfers

Answer (score 0):

I finded the solution with help of @Ellebkey. Follow bellow the code.

*create-transfers.js*

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => (
    queryInterface.createTable('Transfers', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      value: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10, 2),
        defaultValue: 0,
      },
      accountFromId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      accountToId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
    })
      .then(() => (
        queryInterface.addConstraint('Transfers', ['accountFromId'], {
          type: 'foreign key',
          name: 'fk_transfers_account_from',
          references: { // Required field
            table: 'Accounts',
            field: 'id',
          },
          onDelete: 'cascade',
          onUpdate: 'no action',
        })
      ))
      .then(() => (
        queryInterface.addConstraint('Transfers', ['accountToId'], {
          type: 'foreign key',
          name: 'fk_transfers_account_to',
          references: { // Required field
            table: 'Accounts',
            field: 'id',
          },
          onDelete: 'cascade',
          onUpdate: 'no action',
        })
      ))
  ),
  down: queryInterface => queryInterface.dropTable('Transfers'),
};
```

*model/transfers.js*

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Transfers = sequelize.define('Transfers', {
        value: {
            type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 2),
            defaultValue: 0,
        },
        accountFromId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        accountToId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    }, {});
    Transfers.associate = ({ Accounts }) => {
        Transfers.belongsTo(Accounts, { as: 'AccountFrom' });
        Transfers.belongsTo(Accounts, { as: 'AccountTo' });
    };
    return Transfers;
};
```

*controller/transfers.js*

```
const data = await Transfers.find({
    where: {},
    include: [{
        model: database.Accounts,
        as: 'AccountFrom',
    }, {
        model: database.Accounts,
        as: 'AccountTo',
    }],
});
```